# How do I remove JSON Data?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following JSON structure:

```
[{
    "type": 0,
    "id": 1,
    "children": [{
        "type": 0,
        "id": 14
    },
    {
        "type": 0,
        "id": 1
    }]
},
{
    "type": 0,
    "id": 16,
    "children": [{
        "type": 0,
        "id": 15,
        "children": [{
            "type": 0,
            "id": 13
        },
        {
            "type": 0,
            "id": 17
        },
        {
            "type": 0,
            "id": 18
        }]
    }]
}]
```

How do I remove data `"type":0,"id":15` from my JSON?

Comment: JSON begins with curly braces `{}`, not square brackets `[]`. Please use a valid structure and also give more info on your problem.

Comment: @ShammelLee JSON arrays have square brackets instead of curly brackets, so the JSON structure is indeed valid (it's just an array, not an object).

Comment: {} denotes a JSON object. [] denotes a JSON array

Comment: This question is tagged both as JavaScript and PHP; which language do you actually need help with?

Comment: You should format the structure for better readbility

Comment: You should restructure your json to not have so much nesting... It hurts to look at.

Comment: @ShammelLee sorry about that removed your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For javascript,

```js
var input = [{"type":0,"id":1,"children":[{"type":0,"id":14},{"type":0,"id":1}]},{"type":0,"id":16,"children":[{"type":0,"id":15,"children":[{"type":0,"id":13},{"type":0,"id":17},{"type":0,"id":18}]}]}];

function filter(input) {
  return input.filter( (obj) => {
     if (obj.children) obj.children = filter(obj.children);
     return !(obj.type === 0 && obj.id === 15);
  });
}

var result = filter(input);

console.log(result);
```

this way `type = 0` & `id = 15` will be removed recursively, for any level hierarchy inside `children`.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your JSON code, it seems like in the array you have 2 top level objects/properties. In one of those objects contains a inner property that contains  your object that you want to remove, which is { type: 0, id: 15, children: [....] }

Everytime there is a nested property you have to access that inner property's values with dot syntax or brackets. 
For example, here is your JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "type": 0,
    "id": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "type": 0,
        "id": 14
      },
      {
        "type": 0,
        "id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": 0,
    "id": 16,
    "children": [
      {
        "type": 0,
        "id": 15,
        "children": [
          {
            "type": 0,
            "id": 13
          },
          {
            "type": 0,
            "id": 17
          },
          {
            "type": 0,
            "id": 18
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Assuming your whole array is called "soda":
You access it like this:

soda[1].children[0] and that would become the path to get to your data (arrays get to their inner "parts" with indexes remember, like [0] or [1] or [55] and objects get to their inner parts with dot notation .  and then the property name like my example.

soda[1] because soda is an array. Then it used dot notation .children because children is a property of soda[1]. Since soda[1].children is an array again we have to use indexes again, and your object is the only element in that array (remember javascript starts off 0 indexed meaning 0 is the first item, 1 is the 2nd item, etc) so we have to use the rule of using indexes for arrays again, which comes out to be soda[1].children[0] and there is your object you want!